# Failed to load angularjs $templateCache template on dependencies with webpack

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack

Sorry for such a similar question to others out there, but I cant seem to make any of them work.
I understand that when using webpack, the standard way of incluing templates in your angular application is via the require.  ie

```
template: require('./sometemplte.html')
```

I have done that in all of my app code and that works fine.
But i have four dependent libraries that use templateUrl, lets focus on angular-ui-boostrap.

my webpack.conf.js

```
entry: {
  vendor: "./src/vendor.ts",
  app: "./src/ClientApp/app.ts"
},
output: {
  filename: "[name].js",
  path: __dirname + "/wwwroot"
},
module: {
    rules: [
    { test: /\.ts$/,
      loader: "ts-loader"
    }, {
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: 'raw-loader'
    }
```

inside vendor.ts i have

```
require('angular');
require('angular-ui-bootstrap');
```

and inside my app i am simply using the directive

```
<uib-typeahead></uib-typeahead>
```

the code inside my node_modules is not code that I can to modify.  But currently i am getting the following error

```
angular.js:14700 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: uib/template/typeahead/typeahead-popup.html
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$compile/tpload?p0=ui-grid%2Fui-grid&p1=undefined&p2=undefined
```

I verified that the template is within $templateCache in my app.  but for whatever reason it is not available for $compile to do its thing.
So how can i get $templateCache to work with webpack so my external dependencies will work?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to John Reilly i finally figured it out.

There is a plugin called `splitChunks` , which use to be CommonsChunksPlugin.  Once i inlcuded that into my configuration everyting just worked.  I just used the default configuation mentioned here

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/

note: although it is a plugin, it does not go in the `plugins` array.  it goes into the optimization object.

```
entry: {...},
output: {...},
optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    chunks: "async",
    minSize: 30000,
    minChunks: 1,
    maxAsyncRequests: 5,
    maxInitialRequests: 3,
    automaticNameDelimiter: '~',
    name: true,
    cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            priority: -10
        },
    default: {
            minChunks: 2,
            priority: -20,
            reuseExistingChunk: true
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you revert back to templateUrl ?, can you show the full webpack config and how did you build templates.js file (templatecache)